# How exactly does printk work internally?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, debugging

I know `printf` needs help from the OS to do its job.

I also know `printf` does not work in the Linux source code as there is no library. And so we have `printk` for  debugging.

How does `printk` work when the OS is still booting then?

Answer (score 11):

This reference seems to have answers to your questions, titled: [Linux Kernel Development Second Edition](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3).

*excerpt*

> #### printk()
>
> The kernel print function, `printk()`, behaves almost identically to the C library `printf()` function. Indeed, throughout this book we have not made use of any real differences. For most intentions, this is fine; `printk()` is simply the name of the kernel's formatted print function. It does have some differences, however.
>
> #### The Robustness of printk()
>
> One property of `printk()` quickly taken for granted is its robustness. The `printk()` function is callable from just about anywhere in the kernel at any time. It can be called from interrupt or process context. It can be called while a lock is held. It can be called simultaneously on multiple processors, yet it does not require the caller to hold a lock.
>
> It is a resilient function. This is important because the usefulness of `printk()` rests on the fact that it is always there and always works.
>
> #### The Nonrobustness of printk()
>
> A chink in the armor of `printk()`'s robustness does exist. It is unusable before a certain point in the kernel boot process, prior to console initialization. Indeed, if the console is not initialized, where is the output supposed to go?
>
> This is normally not an issue, unless you are debugging issues very early in the boot process (for example, in `setup_arch()`, which performs architecture-specific initialization). Such debugging is a challenge to begin with, and the absence of any sort of print method only compounds the problem.
>
> There is some hope, but not a lot. Hardcore architecture hackers use the hardware that does work (say, a serial port) to communicate with the outside world. Trust me this is not fun for most people. Some supported architectures do implement a sane solution, however and others (i386 included) have patches available that also save the day.
>
> The solution is a `printk()` variant that can output to the console very early in the boot process: `early_printk()`. The behavior is the same as `printk()`, only the name and its capability to work earlier are changed. This is not a portable solution, however, because not all supported architectures have such a method implemented. It might become your best friend, though, if it does.
>
> Unless you need to write to the console very early in the boot process, you can rely on `printk()` to always work.

Answer (score 4):

> How does printK works when the OS is still booting then?

`printk()` goes to the console if possible and the priority is high enough; I'm not sure at what point the kernel initializes a VT to make that feasible but it is obviously fairly early.

`[src]/kernel/printk/printk.c` is pretty well documented.  Console access appears to be controlled via semaphores.  The message is also injected into `/dev/dmsg`, regardless of priority.